# What does `$hash{$key} |= {}` do in Perl?

Tags: perl, initialization, hash-reference

I was wrestling with some Perl that uses hash references.

In the end it turned out that my problem was the line:

```
$myhash{$key} |= {};
```

That is, "assign $myhash{$key} a reference to an empty hash, unless it already has a value".

Dereferencing this and trying to use it as a hash reference, however, resulted in interpreter errors about using a string as a hash reference.

Changing it to:

```
if( ! exists $myhash{$key}) {
  $myhash{$key} = {};
}
```

... made things work.

So I don't have a *problem*. But I'm curious about what was going on.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: In current Perl it would be `$myhash{$key} //= {}` most likely.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perl has shorthand assignment operators. The `||=` operator is often used to set default values for variables due to Perl's feature of having logical operators return the last value evaluated. The problem is that you used `|=` which is a *bitwise* or instead of `||=` which is a *logical* or.

As of Perl 5.10 it's better to use `//=` instead. `//` is the logical defined-or operator and doesn't fail in the corner case where the current value is defined but false.

Answer (score 16):

The reason you're seeing an error about using a string as a hash reference is because you're using the wrong operator. `|=` means "bitwise-or-assign." In other words,

```
  $foo |= $bar;
```

is the same as

```
  $foo = $foo | $bar
```

What's happening in your example is that your new anonymous hash reference is getting stringified, then bitwise-ORed with the value of `$myhash{$key}`. To confuse matters further, if `$myhash{$key}` is undefined at the time, the value is the simple stringification of the hash reference, which looks like `HASH(0x80fc284)`. So if you do a cursory inspection of the structure, it may *look* like a hash reference, but it's not. Here's some useful output via `Data::Dumper`:

```
   perl -MData::Dumper -le '$hash{foo} |= { }; print Dumper \%hash'
   $VAR1 = {
             'foo' => 'HASH(0x80fc284)'
           };
```

And here's what you get when you use the correct operator:

```
  perl -MData::Dumper -le '$hash{foo} ||= { }; print Dumper \%hash'
  $VAR1 = {
            'foo' => {}
          };
```

Comment: Always use `Data::Dumper`, when debugging.

Comment: $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1 can be important; by default, DD will spit out strings that include characters not immediately identifiable to the eye.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem was using "`|=`" (bitwise-or assignment) instead of "`||=`" (assign if false).

Note that your new code is not exactly equivalent.  The difference is that "`$myhash{$key} ||= {}`" will replace existing-but-false values with a hash reference, but the new one won't.  In practice, this is probably not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
my %myhash;
$myhash{$key} ||= {};
```

You can't declare a hash *element* in a `my` clause, as far as I know. You declare the hash first, then add the element in.

Edit: I see you've taken out the `my`. How about trying `||=` instead of `|=`? The former is idiomatic for "lazy" initialisation.

Comment: Silly me. ||=.

I blame a few months' resting from Perl, in other languages.